# VBA MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 run-time error '424'

Tags: vba, rest

I'm trying to call a rest service from VBA

In a module...

```
Sub banana()
  Dim c as Class1
  Set c = New Class1
  c.JiraAccess
End Sub
```

In a class module called Class1

```
Sub JiraAccess()
  Dim b as MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
  Set b = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
  With b
    .Open "POST", "url", False
  End With
End Sub
```

If exclude the call to .Open the code runs but obviously does nothing. I've included a reference to Microsoft XML, v6 (from Tools-Reference)

Including the .Open call results in an 424 error in the title.

Thinking the dll may not be registered, I did so just in case...

`regsvr32 msxml6.dll`

and get a popup saying registration was successful.

I've restarted Excel but get the same run-time error.

Not really sure where to go rom here. I'm on W7.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You're not really using `"url"` for the URL, though, right?

Comment: Where is the call to `.Send` and why are you using `POST` when you have no `sendData`?

Comment: I'm using an internal URL to a JIRA server, it doesn't matter what's in the URL string. I know this because I can't step into the class when debugging to get near that line of code.

Comment: I'm doing a POST because I'm authenticating first, so posting credentials. This is also not the issue for the reason in my previous reply.